# Can a different function fire when double-clicking on an item in jquery UI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, user-interface, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, double-click

Is there a way I could have a different function fire when someone double-clicks on an item inside jQuery UI's Autocomplete?

For example, a single click would take a visitor to one kind of page, whereas a double-click would take a visitor to a different page.

The implementation for this would be for our website's admins. Single-clicking goes to a page. We'd like double-clicking to go to that page's editing form (using Drupal).

Comment: This would be difficult. You'd have to modify the menu widget that autocomplete uses. Additionally, assigning `click` and `dblclick` handlers to the same item is not advisable since `dblclick` events are system dependent and behavior would not be consistent cross-platform.